# Check if two types can be aliased

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a public API function (in a library header) that accepts a `struct foo &`, and that function's internal implementation calls a third-party dependency's function that requires a `struct bar *`.

I do not want to pull in the third party dependency into the public header as the library will be distributed in binary form and this dependency is an implementation detail.

However, I do not intend to attach any additional information to `foo` and instead want to be able to do `reinterpret_cast<bar*>(&foo)` in order to reduce the amount of copies I have to perform (it's a very frequently called function).

Does the standard library have a `type_trait` or some other mechanism to check if the structure of `foo` and `bar` are identical? I understand that this will require more maintanence upkeep on my end to make sure the header matches the internal dependency's type definition as well, but that's fine as it's unlikely to change any time soon.

Ultimately I need something like

```cpp
struct foo {
    int a;
    const char *b;
};

struct bar {
    int c;
    const char *d;
};

static_assert(
    std::is_aliasable_to<foo, bar>::value, //        <-- Is this possible?
    "foo must be structurally equivalent to bar"
);

void public_api_function(foo &f) {
    private_third_party_function(
        reinterpret_cast<bar*>(&f)
    );
}
```

Comment: "*Does the standard library have a `type_trait` or some other mechanism to check if the structure of `foo` and `bar` are identical?*" - no, it does not. What is wrong with simply making `foo` be an alias of `bar`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would require exposing a third party's `bar` header to the users of this library, which the OP said they'd like to avoid

Comment: The OP is looking for some form of easy PIMPL, but I'm not immediately certain which exact implementation is the best suggestion.

Comment: Yep. More or less, I want to be able to prevent a bug if we ever update the dependency and forget to update the struct definition if it were to change in that dependency. A sizeof() assertion, for example, fails if the members were to be re-ordered.

Comment: I use a `pimpl` class for this. I've lost mine, but just whipped this one just now. It's like a hybrid optional/unique_ptr. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f0b19905bcea90c. Here, I create a 32 bit buffer inside `foo`, and place a `bar` into the buffer in the constructor.

Comment: Though in your case since you always know the single impl, this could be optimized to remove the `virtual` methods.

Comment: Now that I've thought more about it, yeah, for pure pimpl, you can strip it _way_ down: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/090c0d4c5d0ab42a, and add `std::hash` support too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<bar*>(&f)` is always UB because of strict-aliasing.

Without strict-aliasing, you could use c++20's `std::is_layout_compatible`, but there isn't any compiler support for that.

You could use a hack like this:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_same_member_type(T foo::*, U bar::*) {
    return std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}

#define HAS_SAME_MEMBER(foo_name, bar_name) (offsetof(foo, foo_name) == offsetof(bar, bar_name) && is_same_member_type(&foo:: foo_name, &bar:: bar_name))

// add more HAS_SAME_MEMBER calls if new members are added
static_assert(
    sizeof(foo) == sizeof(bar) &&
    std::is_standard_layout_v<foo> && std::is_standard_layout_v<bar> &&
    HAS_SAME_MEMBER(a, c) &&
    HAS_SAME_MEMBER(b, d),
    "foo must be structurally equivalent to bar"
);

#undef HAS_SAME_MEMBER
```

Comment: Man, you're not kidding - `is_layout_compatible` simply hasn't been worked on by any compiler vendor. Even checking the latest clang-12 release shows no sign of anything with that name in the libraries. This is probably the best I'll do for now, which is sufficient as it's a small struct. Thank you :)

Comment: There is standard trait `std::is_corresponding_member` which could be used in place of the macro. I don't know if vendors have implemented  that yet either.